# Row 1 doesn't contain data of all columns

Tags: mysql, csv

Пытаюсь импортировать csv файл в MySQL.Вот сам файл :

> idTelephone,Surname,Name
>
> "+380500719216","Sckoriy","Sergey"

Вот таким образом импортирую :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'E:\Test.csv'
INTO TABLE `testcvs`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY 'n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Вот самая таблица :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбрасывает такое исключение :

```
16:43:36    LOAD DATA INFILE 'E:\Test.csv' INTO TABLE `testcvs` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY 'n' IGNORE 1 ROWS  Error Code: 1261. Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns    0.000 sec
```

Comment: ``LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'``

Comment: Между строчкой с заголовками и данным есть пустая строка?

Comment: Эникейщик , спасибо!!!Работает